# Sage VirtualBox package for Windows

Tags: math, virtualbox, sage

I would like to use SAGE for some of my projects (under Windows). On the sagemath.org website I found only VMWare packages, but I would like to use VirtualBox instead. I got lost on the website.
Could someone help me to find download link for SAGE VirtualBox package for Windows?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The question is solved:

> William Stein
>   Fri Jul 30 13:00:13 2010
>   Hi,
>
> Sage-VirtualBox is not supported now.
>   Sage-VMware generally works much better for Windows users, in my experience.
>   You should install vmware player (free) and use the vmware virtual machine.
>
> -- William

Answer (score 1):

As of January 30, 2011 (in regards to Ypsilon IV's answer), that might still have been correct.  NOW, it turns out that Virtual Box IS supported and VMWare is NOT.  There are instructions that are easy to follow for installation of Sage in Virtual Box at:

http://wiki.sagemath.org/SageAppliance